# Which is the best/standard practice with two-way if-else statement

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering what's the better solution in these situations, or what would the coding standard say about this at a company?

```
        if (this.State == NetworkState.Server)
        {
            //...
        }
        else if (this.State == NetworkState.Client)
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //some error throwing or printing
        }
```

or

```
        if (this.State == NetworkState.Server)
        {
            //...
        }          
        else
        {
            //sure its client here
        }
```

I feel like the first one is more readable, because you can clearly see that client is the other state, but it also makes the code longer, and sometimes I can't really do much more than print "this should never happen" in the third case. Is there a definite better solution?

Comment: If you're dealing with an enum, you can't be sure that `Client` is the value in an `else` block because you could receive an invalid value for the enum in question. You could use a `switch` statement instead of using `if/else` and throw an exception in the `default` clause.

Comment: @Lee Even if the enum has only two values like here?

Comment: What happens 2 years from now when someone introduces a new NetworkState.SomethingElse to your code?

Comment: @Innkeeper - Yes even then since you can cast from the underlying integral type to the enum type, for example `(NetworkState.Server)(-1)` or some other value which is out of range.

Comment: @DanPichelman Ok, you have a point, switch is better, just the idea of using a switch block with just two branches as of this day just seemed strange to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It makes more sense to use a switch statement here.

```
 switch(this.State)
 {
     case NetworkState.Server:
        //...
        break;
     case NetworkState.Client:
        //...
        break;
     default:
        //some error throwing or printing
        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("An unsupported enumeration value {0}.{1} was used.  Processing for the case is not supported because it has not been explicitly implemented.", typeof(NetworkState).Name, this.State), new NotImplementedException());
 }
```

It makes the fact explicit that the only condition you are considering is the enumerated value.  With an if statement, you would have to read each additional "if" to make sure that there are not other conditions that affect the logic.

**Edit:** I just noticed the part of your question that asks how to handle the non-matching case.  I added an exception there that explains the issue.  I like to do this, because in reality - the only times that I will ever get to the `default` clause is if: (1) I have forgotten an option, and need to implemented it; or, (2) a value has been added to the enumeration since the original code was written.  In either case, **developer attention** is needed, rather than processing, so it seems like throwing an error to indicating this necessity would be the only rational response.

Comment: The `default` is most important - by throwing/reporting an error here, you can detect cases where a new enumerated value has been added and the code has not been updated to handle it.

Comment: I see the reasons now, thank you. Oldest suggestion of switch, so this is accepted.

Comment: @Innkeeper, In general, you **do** need to break in the default case.  However, if you `return` a value or throw an exception in any case (`break` or otherwise), then you can omit the `break` clause.  My code is an example of when you don't need to `break` (because of the exception).  If the exception were absent, then you would get an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(this.State)
{
    case NetworkState.Server:
    ...
    default: throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

It keeps it safer in case someone adds another `NetworkState` and doesn't know about this method.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best combination of those options is:

```
    if (this.State == NetworkState.Server)
    {
        //...
    }          
    else // State == Client
    {
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. When the value can only be a bool, an `if else` is always better.

This is ugly:

```
if (true){
  [...]
else if (false){
  [...]
else{
  // can never happen
}
```

This is better:

```
if (true){ 
  [...]
else{
  [...]
}
```

But in the case of an enum using an `if` might not seem like the best idea. Like you said, it's nice to know the enum value each `branch` is for. I think a switch statement solves that problem.

```
switch(this.State){
  case NetworkState.Server:
    [...]
    break;
  case NetworkState.Client:
    [...]
    break;
  default:
    // if this can't happen, how about throwing an exception?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a switch case statement?

```
switch(this.State)
{
    case NetworkState.Server:
    //...
    break;

    case NetworkState.Client:
    //...
    break;

    default: 
    //some error throwing or printing
}
```